# How to workaround Direct Oracle Access failure with table names that lead by numeric characters?

Tags: oracle, delphi, c++builder, double-quotes

Does anyone know how to make Direct Oracle Access work with queries involving tables that lead with numeric characters.

The original tables were created with double quotes and we form our queries with double quotes around the table names.  But DOA purposefully strips the double quotes when performing its internal/intermediate queries.  This leads to access violations in our application.

Unfortunately, modifying the table names at this point is not feasible, and hacking into the DOA source is not something we want to do.

Has anyone else experienced this, and if so, how have you gotten around the problem.

Unfortunately, this is a system I inherited and the double quoted table names are pervasive.

Thank you!!

Comment: just a guess: have you tried to use square brackets around the table names? e.g. `select * from [1table]`

Comment: Maybe prepending the database name works?

Comment: Why don't you submit your question to Allround Automations support? http://www.allroundautomations.com

Answer (score 0):

create a synonym and reference that from your application instead.

```
SQL> create table "1table" (id  number);

Table created.
SQL> create synonym foo for "1table";

Synonym created.

SQL> select  * from foo;

no rows selected

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Unfortunately, this won't work for us.  It would require us to add another layer of processing to manage and utilize the synonyms.  There are far too many existing tables and our clients have already generated many themselves.

Comment: the synonym solution doesn't work because internally DOA resolves the synonyms and works on the original objects